# What parts of the Hobbit book are covered by the first film?

Tags: movie, tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

The Hobbit is being adapted to film in several parts, the first of which is titled: "*The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey*"

What parts of the Hobbit book are covered by this film?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the early reviews [(for example)](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/movie/hobbit-an-unexpected-journey/review/397416) it sounds like the movie ends with the dwarves and Bilbo trapped by Wolves and Orcs after getting through the Misty Mountains.

Comment: Thanks @Ward and on dwarves vs dwarfs http://valarguild.org/varda/Tolkien/encyc/articles/d/dwarves/dwarfpluralof.htm

Comment: I originally used "dwarves" but my browser underlined it as a mistake, so I changed it.

Comment: Why don't browsers know these things?!

Comment: Never trust a machine to spell things correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The movie ends right after the company are rescued by the Eagles. They're deposited on a high rock, which gives them their first glimpse of the Lonely Mountain off in the distance. Then there's a bit with a bird (which one of the dwarves mistakes for a raven, like in the prophecy, but Gandalf gently corrects him that it's actually a thrush) and a teaser of Smaug in a pile of gold, and then roll credits.

It's been a long, long time since I read the book, but I think that pretty much every major part of the book is on the screen, plus some stuff that's only alluded to, plus some stuff that's not alluded to but sorta-kinda assumed, plus some stuff that's not assumed but matches the timeline, plus some stuff that happens on a different timeline... not to mention gratuitous battle scenes, and some snot. But I think the latter is in the book.

Comment: This is the end of the 6th chapter of the book, so roughly a third of the way through.